# What does loc = $('<a>', {href:window.location})[0]; mean?

Tags: jquery, url, href

I have seen `loc = $('<a>', {href:window.location})[0];` appearing in alot of samples and they all seem to take it for granted. I am not new to jQuery, but only recently decided to start looking after my URLs, so my question is what does the weird combination of syntaxes mean?

Would appreciate if you could provide a usage example, or a slightly different reference that refers to the same thing that the `loc` here does.

Thank you!

Comment: `$('<a>', {href:window.location})` create a jquery object  and `[0]` return underlying DOM element

Comment: `$('<a>', {href:window.location})` creates a jquery object and adding `[0]` gets a dom element like `<a href="thelocation"></a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('<a>', {href:window.location})` create a jquery object and `[0]` is used here to access underlying DOM element. You can also use [`get(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to access underlying DOM element.

```js
loc = $('<a>', {href:window.location});
console.log(loc[0]);
console.log(loc);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i just answered the same, i guess.

Answer (score 1):

The code `loc = $('<a>', {href:window.location})` gives you the jquery version object and `[0]` gives you the DOM node created by it with no extra options.

```js
var loc = $('<a>', {href:window.location});

console.log(loc);
console.log(loc[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code creates new `a` element with href attribute equals to current `window.location` and assigns it to `loc`variable.